# sudo apt-get update error.

Tags: apt, 18.04, updates, files, connection

Version 18.04 sudo apt-get update

I am trying to "update" but am getting the following message:

```
Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
  Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
  Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
  Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
  Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-updates/InRelease Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-backports/InRelease Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-security/InRelease Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or cold ones used instead.
```

I have tried to follow various solutions for this but cannot resolve it.

I have tried to update using ethernet in case it was the wifi. I still get the same error.

I have tried to do:

```
echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" | sudo tee /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base > /dev/nell
```

but get

`tee: /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 0):

I think you're on a right track.

`Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'` indicates some kind of a network issue, possible a DNS failure.

Maybe let's figure the Ethernet first (wifi should work out-of-the box most of the times, but there are some problematic chipsets).

In ubuntu uses network manager and we check the settings in GUI:

1. Open network settings

   1.1. Hit the windows key

   1.2. Type `settings`

   1.3. Go to `Network` at the bottom
2. Is the `Wired` indicated as connected?

[image: wired network settings]

3. Does the configuration (after clicking the `gear` icon) look sane?

[image: network details]

You can put your dns settings there in the `IPv4` tab.

*I'm on ubuntu 18.10, but it should look similar in 18.04 except a different theme*

Comment: Thank you for your reply! In Network it just shows VPN and Network Proxy, there's no "Wired" option there

Comment: Can you actually connect to internet? Either on wifi or ethernet? E.g. you can test with `ping google.com` or `ping 8.8.8.8`

Comment: I can connect the actual machine (MacBook Pro) by either wifi or ethernet (I am using it now but am in Safari), but it seems that when using VM/Ubuntu I am not connected. Under wifi is says "no wifi adapter found"

Comment: ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: imp_seq=2 ttl=63 time=4.54 ms

Comment: Oh, this is under Virtualbox, maybe this link will help https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37122/virtualbox-two-network-interfaces-nat-and-host-only-ones-in-a-debian-guest-on ?

Comment: I am still no further forward

Comment: What's your network settings in Virtualbox? (If you click on the VM, **Settings** and then **Network** and then adapters 1, 2, ...?

Comment: adapter 1 was NAT but after reading through various posts I changed the setting to bridged but it still hasn't worked